# What is Source Application in OLE

Tags: vb.net, oledb, ole

I have some questions about Object Linking and Embedding (Visual Basic)

```
1. What is  meant by Source Application in OLE?
2. Why it is used ?
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Q: Are you studying for an archaelogy exam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM/ActiveX (which includes OLE) had lots of terminology and acronyms.  Like "QI", "ROT" and "BSTR", to name a few :;  But, as far as I know, "Source Application" wasn't among them.

Q: Where exactly did you encounter the term?  In what context was it used?

SUGGESTION:

COM/ActiveX had "in proc servers" (.dlls) and "out of proc servers" (.exe's).  I suspect maybe "Source Application" might refer to an out of proc server, like MS-Word or Excel?